# Postgres hash index performance

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with 10 million entries, and one of the column is email address. 
I want to create a hash index on this column since the queries are all on equality comparisons.

Database: Postgres 8.3.3
Machine: 24GB Ram and 16 cores.

Hash index creation takes about 51 minutes, however, if I create a hash index on lower case of the email address, it takes less than 3 minutes!

Example:

- `create index xyz on table_xyz using hash(email)`: Takes 51 minutes to create this index
- `create index xyz on table_xyz using hash(lower(email))`: Takes 3 minutes to create this index.

My maintenance_work_mem is set to 16MB.
shared_buffers = 1GB

What explains this behavior?

Comment: Did this happen once, or did you try it a second time?

Comment: I tried 4 times and got the same result.

Comment: I don't know what the answer here is (so, I'm just making a comment).  Are you aware that hash indexes are discouraged?  From the 8.3 docs... *Note: Testing has shown PostgreSQL's hash indexes to perform no better than B-tree indexes, and the index size and build time for hash indexes is much worse. Furthermore, hash index operations are not presently WAL-logged, so hash indexes might need to be rebuilt with REINDEX after a database crash. For these reasons, hash index use is presently discouraged.*

Comment: 8.3.3? Time to upgrade, at the very minimum you need to update URGENTLY to 8.3.21, you're missing something like three years of bug fixes including a couple of nasty ones. Then start planning a move to 9.1 or 9.2 before support for 8.3 is dropped completely.

Comment: Check dba instead of stackexchange